# Mathematical reasoning: Sun rises or moon sets - the 'or' used is here is exclusive or inclusive?

Tags: logic

*State whether the "Or" used is "exclusive" or "inclusive"? Give reasons*

> **Sun rises or Moon sets**

Comment: Is that the whole of the question? I can't make sense of it at all.

Comment: Pay no attention to stupid examples like the one you have on your hand, you can find far better examples in other books. The author's lack of clarity and having no idea of movement of sun and the moon is causing nonconstructive problem for you. Best just look at better more relavent and clear examples that will be of use.

Comment: You might want to visit this page to better understand exclusive and inclusive or.

[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246249/what-is-the-difference-between-inclusive-and-exclusive-or)

I personally believe that it is inclusive.

Comment: I noticed you edited the post to remove the fact that you found it said the answer was XOR and not OR. You shouldn't remove that, because it says you spent some time thinking about it before you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both events may happen in the same time, the "or" is "inclusive".